# Analytics on a PHP API

Tags: php, api, google-analytics, analytics

I recently completed my first API in PHP. It is hosted at a public URL and accessed by a couple of my own mobile apps and websites. Based on a couple of parameters passed in, it pulls some data from my database and returns some JSON.

I would like to know some details about how often the API is accessed, and by what kind of clients.

Can I use google analytics for this? I have used it successfully on some websites in the same domain, but when I include the analytics php link and access the API, nothing is recorded.

Any gotchas I could be missing? Or is Google analytics only useable on web pages?

Answer (score 0):

Google analytics isnt just for montiring websites, you can also use it to monitor mobile applications.

You might be able to monitor your API with the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference#overview) this should let you send info about the preformance of your api, and log the things you are talking about.

Note: I havent tried it but would love to hear from you if this works.